# PHP get specific string from url before and after unknown characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I know it may sound as a common question but I have difficulty understanding this process.
So I have this string:

```
http://domain.com/campaign/tgadv?redirect
```

And I need to get only the word "tgadv". But I don't know that the word is "tgadv", it could be whatever.

Also the url itself may change and become:

```
http://domain.com/campaign/tgadv
```

or

```
http://domain.com/campaign/tgadv/
```

So what I need is to create a function that will get whatever word is **after campaign** and **before any other particular character**. That's the logic..
The only certain thing is that the word will come after the word **campaign/** and that any other character that will be after the word we are searching is a special one ( i.e. / or ? )

I tried understanding `preg_match` but really cannot get any good result from it..

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: [Got speed](http://regex101.com/r/zS2xD3) ?

Comment: Try to check on this link. Hope you'll find your answer here. http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/get-current-page-url.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a regex for that. I would use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`basename`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$bits =  parse_url('http://domain.com/campaign/tgadv?redirect');
$filename = basename($bits['path']);
echo $filename;
```

However, if want a regex solution, use something like this:

```
$pattern = '~(.*)/(.*)(\?.*)~';
preg_match($pattern, 'http://domain.com/campaign/tgadv?redirect', $matches);
$filename = $matches[2];
echo $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `preg_match` sounds like the perfect solution to this problem. I assume you are having problems with the regex?

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://domain.com/campaign/tgadv/";
$pattern = "@campaign/([^/\?]+)@";
preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);

// $matches[1] will contain tgadv.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = "http://domain.com/campaign/tgadv?redirect";
$url_parts = parse_url($path);
$tgadv = strrchr($url_parts['path'], '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a regex to accomplish this. You can do it using [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) and [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

For example:

```
$str = '....Your string...';
$offset = stripos($str, 'campaign/');
if ( $offset === false ){
    //error, end of h4 tag wasn't found
}
$offset += strlen('campaign/');
$newStr = substr($str, $offset);
```

At this point $newStr will have all the text after 'campaign/'.

You then just need to use a similar process to find the special character position and use substr() to strip the string you want out.

Comment: After seeing the other answers, parse_url() would seem like a better option that I had overlooked...

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the good old string functions in this case, no need to involve regexps.

First find the string `/campaign/`, then take the substring with everything after it (`tgadv/asd/whatever/?redirect`), then find the next `/` or `?` after the start of the string, and everything in between will be what you need (`tgadv`).